# How to reduce time complexity or improve the efficiency of the program finding gaps of month using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Input is like this

```
Data    Id
201505  A
201507  A
201509  A
200001  B
200001  C
200002  C
200005  C
```

i am finding date gaps and using this.But it is taking too long time to complete the function for large data how can i reduce time complexity of

```
#convert to datetimes
month['data'] = pd.to_datetime(month['data'], format='%Y%m')
#resample by start of months with asfreq
mdf = month.set_index('data').groupby(['series_id','symbol'])['series_id'].resample('MS').asfreq().rename('val').reset_index()
x = mdf['val'].notnull().rename('g')
#create index by cumulative sum for unique groups for consecutive NaNs
mdf.index = x.cumsum()
#filter only NaNs row and aggregate first, last and count.
mdf = (mdf[~x.values].groupby(['series_id','symbol','g'])['data'].agg(['first','last','size']).reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index())

print mdf

 Id      first       last  size
0  A 2015-06-01 2015-06-01     1
1  A 2015-08-01 2015-08-01     1
2  B 2000-02-01 2000-02-01     1
3  C 2003-03-01 2003-04-01     2
```

How can i reduce the time complexity or some other way to find the date gaps.

Comment: What do you mean by date gaps

Comment: missing months for id, for example id A missing a month 201505 to 201507 missing month is 201506

Comment: hmm ok, but then in your output, why is there the row with ID 1

Comment: since 201508 is the last value in your dataframe, there is no gap

Comment: sorry i have updated the input it is 201509  201508 is missing.

Comment: got it, I'll work on an answer

Answer (score 1):

The assumptions made are the following:

- All values in the Data column are unique, even across groups
- The data in the data column are integers
- The data is sorted by group first and then by value.

Here is my algorithm (mdf is the input df):

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':mdf['Id'],'First':mdf['Data']+1,'Last':(mdf['Data']-1).shift(-1)})
df2 = df2.groupby('Id').apply(lambda g: g[g['Data'] != g['Data'].max()]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2[~df['First'].isin(mdf['Data'])&~df['Last'].isin(mdf['Data'])])
```

Comment: the data in the columns are datetime with format='%Y%m' and also your code is giving error  lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: your algorithm is not working.even not displaying any output it has showing errors

Comment: Did you read the assumptions man, I said the data has to be integers. Can you convert them?

Comment: I converted them to integers.now it is getting error lamda data column

Answer (score 1):

So using a bit the idea @RushabhMehta, you can us [pd.DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) to create the output dataframe. Your input dataframe is called `month`, with column 'data' and 'series_id', according to your code. Here is the idea:

```
month['data'] = pd.to_datetime(month['data'], format='%Y%m')
month = month.sort_values(['series_id','data'])
# create mdf with the column you want
mdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id':month.series_id, 'first':month.data + pd.DateOffset(months=1), 
                    'last': (month.groupby('series_id').data.shift(-1) - pd.DateOffset(months=1))})
```

Note how the column 'last' is created, using `groupby`, `shift` the value and substract a month with `pd.DateOffset(months=1)`. Now select only the rows where the date in 'first' is before the one in 'last' and create the column size such as:

```
mdf = mdf.loc[mdf['first'] <= mdf['last']]
mdf['size'] = (mdf['last']- mdf['first']).astype('timedelta64[M]')+1
```

`mdf` looks like:

```
       first Id       last  size
0 2015-06-01  A 2015-06-01   1.0
1 2015-08-01  A 2015-08-01   1.0
3 2000-02-01  B 2000-02-01   1.0
6 2000-03-01  C 2000-04-01   2.0
```

Just need to reorder column and `reset_index` if you want.

Comment: i am getting error mdf = mdf.loc[mdf.first <= mdf.last] in this function that is key error true.

Comment: @raam indeed, it's because 'first' and 'last' are names for column I should not use like this. Try `mdf.loc[mdf['first'] <= mdf['last']]` should work

Comment: @raam and same for after `mdf['size'] = (mdf['last']- mdf['first'] ).astype('timedelta64[M]')+1`

Comment: i am getting all the data in mdf i need only the gaps

Comment: @raam my first comment meant: `mdf = mdf.loc[mdf['first'] <= mdf['last']]`, sorry it was not clear as I knew were the keyerror was. end then create the column size

Comment: I have noticed that difference sometimes getting wrong...which means first 2005-02-01 last 2005-05-01 size should be 4 but your logic is getting 3.for some data difference is getting -1.can I know where the error is?

Comment: @raam I think the problem is `astype('timedelta64[M]')` as not all the months have the same number of days. I think you can replace the last line of code by: `mdf['size'] = (mdf['last'].dt.year - mdf['first'].dt.year)*12 + (mdf['last'].dt.month - mdf['first'].dt.month)+1`, it should be more rigourous

Comment: For year gap what should i multiply mdf['size'] = (mdf['last'].dt.year - mdf['first'].dt.year)*365 + (mdf['last'].dt.month - mdf['first'].dt.month)+1 is this way.or any other way

Comment: @raam in year gap? why do you multiply by 365?

Comment: For year gap what should i multiply mdf['size'] = (mdf['last'].dt.year - mdf['first'].dt.year) + (mdf['last'].dt.month - mdf['first'].dt.month)+1 is this way.or any other way

Comment: @raam if I understand well, I would divide the number of month by 12 to get it as "year": `mdf['size'] = (mdf['last'].dt.year - mdf['first'].dt.year) + ((mdf['last'].dt.month - mdf['first'].dt.month)+1)/12.

Comment: ya.i got the solution with out divide by 12..i have a some confusion that how to calculate week and days gap..can you give the function.

Comment: @raam for days, it's just `mdf['last']- mdf['first']`. Then for weeks, divide by 7 I would say. you might need `+1` somewhere, depending if you want to take into account bounds or not

Comment: can you give solution for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746797/find-that-start-date-and-end-dates-are-available-using-python-pandas

Comment: can you give the answer to this question how to compare or merge two data frames using python pandas?

Comment: can we reduce the complexity of this logic df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'start': pd.date_range(row.start, row.end, freq='AS'),'series_id': row.series_id}, columns=['start', 'id']) 
           for i, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True) this logic extract the start date and end for id.

Comment: can we reduce or we can have different logic for this df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.id, pd.date_range(r.start, r.end, freq='AS')) for r in df.itertuples()]) .reset_index()).Please Help me.

Comment: can you give solution for thisid start end data 
1 2001 2003 [[2001,1.4],[2002,23],[2004,56]] 
2 2002 2005 [[2003,1],[2004,1],[2005,1]] 

id start 
1 2001 
1 2002 
1 2003 
2 2002 
2 2003 
2 2004 
2 2005 like this.I have used to itertuples and iterrows but it is getting more complex.I want to reduce the time complexity for it