# Find that start date and end dates are available using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe like this

```
year  end         id   start                          
 1949  1954.0      ABc  1949.0    
 1950  1954.0      ABc  1949.0   
 1951  1954.0      ABc  1949.0    
 1952  1954.0      ABc  1949.0    
 1953  1954.0      ABc  1949.0    
 1954  1954.0      ABc  1949.0

 1950  1954.0      xyz  1949.0   
 1951  1954.0      xyz  1949.0    
 1952  1954.0      xyz  1949.0    
 1953  1954.0      xyz  1949.0    
 1954  1954.0      xyz  1949.0

 1949  1954.0      cde  1949.0    
 1950  1954.0      cde  1949.0   
 1951  1954.0      cde  1949.0    
 1952  1954.0      cde  1949.0    
 1953  1954.0      cde  1949.0
```

I have to find the missing year for that id the output should be like this

```
 year end id start
 1949 1954 xyz 1949
 1954 1954 cde 1949
```

We have to check whether the start and end for that id is available or not.

How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work; see comments in code for clarification on what I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

# reading the dataframe from your sample
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df['start'] = df['start'].astype('int')
df['end'] = df['end'].astype('int')


# create a function that finds the min start date and max end date
def findRange(row):
    return list(range(row['startMin'], row['endMax']+1))

# create three groupped dataframes and create a list for year start min and start max
year_list = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('id')['year'].apply(list))
start_min = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('id')['start'].apply(min)).rename(columns={'start':'startMin'})
end_max = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('id')['end'].apply(max)).rename(columns={'end':'endMax'})

# apply the findRange function for each grouped ID to see the date range we are looking for
dfs = [year_list,start_min,end_max]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='id'), dfs)
df_final['Range'] = df_final.apply(findRange, axis=1)
df_final.reset_index(inplace=True)

# create a noMatch function to find all the values in list year that are not in the range created above
def noMatch(a, b):
    return [x for x in b if x not in a]

# use a for loop to iterate through all the rows and find the missing year
df1 = []
for i in range(0, len(df_final)):
    df1.append(noMatch(df_final['year'][i],df_final['Range'][i]))

# create a new dataframe and get your desiered output: my column names are different and in a different order;
# however, the output is the same as your desired output
missing_year = pd.DataFrame(df1).rename(columns={0:'missingYear'})
df_concat = pd.concat([df_final, missing_year], axis=1)
df_concat = df_concat[['id','startMin','endMax','missingYear']]
df_concat = df_concat[df_concat['missingYear'].notnull()]
df_concat['missingYear'] = df_concat['missingYear'].astype('int')
df_concat


    id   startMin   endMax  missingYear
1   cde   1949      1954    1954
2   xyz   1949      1954    1949
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `groupby` and set difference like:

```
# first convert to integer
df['start'] = df['start'].astype('int')
df['end'] = df['end'].astype('int')
print (df.groupby(['id','start','end'])
          .apply(lambda x: set(range(x.start.iloc[0], x.end.iloc[0]+1))-set(x.year)))
id   start  end 
ABc  1949   1954        {}
cde  1949   1954    {1954}
xyz  1949   1954    {1949}
dtype: object
```

Now if you want the output format you ask, cahnge the `set` to a `list`, add `dropna`, `astype` and `reset_index`:

```
df_missing = (df.groupby(['id','start','end'])
                .apply(lambda x: [*(set(range(x.start.iloc[0], x.end.iloc[0]+1))-set(x.year))])
                .str[0].dropna().astype(int).reset_index(name='missing_year'))
print (df_missing)
    id  start   end  missing_year
0  cde   1949  1954          1954
1  xyz   1949  1954          1949
```

Comment: i am getting wrong output.1953 id cde which should be 1954

Comment: @raam as you can see, the output is correct here. so maybe there is an error in your original data you use. Note: the second code (the one starting with `df_missing = ...`) won't be good for multiple missing years, as it selects only the first (and unique according to your question) missing year.

Comment: @ Ben.T this is the data frame series_id  start   end  data
0  A       2008  2017  2011
1  A       2008  2017  2015
2  A       2008  2017  2009
3  A       2008  2017  2010
4  A       2008  2017  2014
5  A       2008  2017  2016
6  A       2008  2017  2012
7  A       2008  2017  2013 for this out should be 2017 but it is displaying 2016

Comment: the order of data may varry

Comment: @raam with the data you gave in the comment, I got two missing years (2008 and 2017) but no 2016 and as I said, in `df_missing` I have only 2008 as it keep only one missing year, if any. and the order of data should not matter as `set` are not ordered

Comment: But for me 2016 is showing.for first logic i am getting series_id  start  end
A          2008   2017    {2016, 2017, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013,2014,2015}  using second logic it is displaying like this.  series_id  start   end  missing_year
0         A   2008  2017          2016 actually their is no missing year but it is still showing 2016

Comment: @raam it seems that the error comes from the `- set(x.year)` then. In the example you gave in the comment, the name of the column `year` has been replace by `data` so you change it to `- set(x.data)` right?

Comment: I have changed it even it is getting missing year 2016.their is no Miss ing

Comment: @raam sorry but can't help you further as I can't reproduce the result you get